# SQL query for finding all distinct rows that have most recent date associated with the same value in separate column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL, and I have 3 tables: client, asset, balance. The client table has client information and each client has a client_id. The asset table holds the 'ticker' for each asset_id. The balance table has columns: 'client_id', 'asset_id', 'timestamp', 'amount'.

I am interested in querying for the most recent balance for a given client_id. By 'most recent balance' I mean getting the latest timestamp, along with the ticker and amount for each asset, all associated with the client_id in question. The problem is, that not all assets are updated simultaneously. If they were, then I could simply do something like this if I wanted the latest balance for client_id = 3:

```
select ticker, timestamp, amount
from balance inner join asset on asset_id = asset.id
and timestamp = (select max(timestamp)
        from balance
        where client_id = 3);
```

This would work if all assets had been updated (regardless of change) for every new addition to the table, resulting in all assets having the same most recent timestamp. However, since I do not want to update the balance for an asset that has not changed, it no longer works. If I make a new addition, for example to increase the amount of one specific asset for a client, and therefore that timestamp is now the most recent for all timestamps associated with that client, the query above will only return that single asset, not all assets associated with the client since it looks for the 'max(timestamp)'

How do I change the above query to look for the max timestamp PER asset for the given client id?

I apologize if this is confusing, I have never been good with SQL queries and am lost having spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (client_id) ticker, timestamp, amount
from balance b inner join
     asset a
     on b.asset_id = a.asset.id
order by client_id, timestamp desc;
```

`distinct on` is a very handy Postgres extension.  It returns one row for the keys in parentheses.  The row is the first based on the `order by` clause (based on the ordering *after* the specified keys).

Comment: In both places where you had 'client_id' I had to replace that with 'ticker' for it to do what I was looking for, and I also had to add the "where client_id = __' clause to get a specific client's balance. But now it works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the window function ROW_NUMBER. I am not sure it is available in PostgreSQL, but it is standard SQL for quit some time.

```
select ticker, timestamp, amount
from
(
    select 
        ticker, 
        row_number() over (partition by asset_id order by timestamp desc) as row_num
        timestamp, 
        amount
    from balance 
    inner join asset on asset_id = asset.id
    where client_id = 3
) t
where t.row_num = 1
;
```

ROW_NUMBER function will ORDER your query by timestamp desc, so column "row_num"=1 will be the last one.
The partition clause will ensure it is separated by asset_id, so each asset id has its own "last timestamp".

Important! If you do not use client_id as a filter, you will need to partition by client_id also.